# Hyperlink Formula field does not work

Tags: formula-field, hyperlink

I have created a custom Formula field for a Travel object and inserted HYPERLINK formula:

HYPERLINK( "https://apps.fas.usda.gov/visa_requirements/index.asp" , "Link to Foreign Agricultural Service Country Visa Requirements")

It is in the appropriate page layouts. I am Previewing it and when I click on it I get an error message although Syntax is fine.

Any ideas?

Image of page layout preview where when clicked the link opens a new browser with error and the URL when clicked goes to this page:

https://cloudapps-usda-gov--arsdev2.cs32.my.salesforce.com/setup/layout/preview.jsp?isdtp=p1#

[image]

Comment: I think this is because of preview. Save layout and try on actual record.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in both Classic and Lightning.  You just can't click it in the Lightning preview mode, I think.